# How to request data from nested API using terraform

Tags: json, for-loop, networking, terraform

I am using URL with JSON file to access data

The first element of every object is a URL that has another JSON file with more data

Following the first URL again there is a third JSON file with following data in it

from these three JSON files i would like to get some data and put them together in a map for example:

```
url = ****
apn = ****
operator = ****
iprange = ****
network = ****`
```

I tried creating a map with all of the data per network so i could filter out later the info that i needed but I cant figure out how to get the data out of the nested urls.

Comment: Please avoid using images of code, it makes it a lot more difficult to troubleshoot

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of providers you could use to make http requests:

- https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/http/latest/docs
- https://registry.terraform.io/providers/marcofranssen/curl/latest/docs

---

Here is a sample using the `hashicorp/http` :

```
data "http" "petstore_available" {
  url    = "https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/pet/findByStatus?status=available"
  method = "GET"

  request_headers = { Accept = "application/json" }
}

locals {
  response_body = jsondecode(data.http.petstore_available.response_body)
  ids           = sort([for x in local.response_body : x.id if x.id < 20])
}

data "http" "petstore_pets" {
  for_each = toset(local.ids)
  url      = "https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/pet/${each.value}"
  method   = "GET"

  request_headers = { Accept = "application/json" }
}

locals {
  pets = [
    for k, v in data.http.petstore_pets : {
      id     = k
      name   = jsondecode(v.response_body).name,
      status = jsondecode(v.response_body).status,
    } if try(jsondecode(v.response_body).name, "") != ""
  ]
}

output "pets" {
  value = local.pets
}
```

- In the `data "http" "petstore_available"` we get all the pets available
- We extract a list of pet ids with a loop:
  `for x in local.response_body : x.id`
  **Remember this is just an example**, In your case instead of getting the `id` you will get the `url` that is what we will use for the second http request...
- Then in `data "http" "petstore_pets"` we loop over those ids to get more information
- Finally in the `local.pets` we extract a map with some info on those pets that have a name

---

If we run a TF plan on that we get:

```txt
Changes to Outputs:
  + pets = [
      + {
          + id     = "1"
          + name   = "Romashka"
          + status = "available"
        },
      + {
          + id     = "13"
          + name   = "Rebeca"
          + status = "available"
        },
      + {
          + id     = "16"
          + name   = "Lauretta"
          + status = "available"
        },
      + {
          + id     = "19"
          + name   = "Tiny"
          + status = "available"
        },
    ]
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, gathering the data from the nested json's worked. I am still struggeling to match the data together out of the different json's.  This is how i am currently doing it 'data "http" "first" {
  url = "http://10.221.185.28:8000/v1/network/"
  method = "GET"
  request_headers = { Accept = "application/json" }
}

locals {
  network_list     = jsondecode(data.http.first.response_body)
  colibriNetworkId  = sort([for x in local.network_list : x.colibriNetworkId])
  url_first         = [for x in local.network_list : x.url]
}'

Comment: data "http" "second" {
  for_each = toset(local.url_first)
  url      = each.value
  method   = "GET"
  request_headers = { Accept = "application/json" }
}

locals {
  network_instance = {
    for url, response in data.http.second : url => jsondecode(response.body)
  }
  url_second = [for x in local.network_instance : x.url]
}

Comment: data "http" "third" {
  for_each = toset(local.url_second)
  url      = each.value
  method   = "GET"
  request_headers = { Accept = "application/json" }
}

locals {
  iprange_list = {
    for url, response in data.http.third : 
    url => jsondecode(response.body) if try(response.body) != ""
  } 
  # url_third = [for x in local.iprange_list : x.url if try(x.url, "") != ""
  # ]
}

Comment: I would like to gather data from the three jsons and put them together in one local. For example locals {
  adresses = [
    name = network_list.name (from the first json file)
    operator = network_instance.operator (from the second json file)
    iprange = iprange_list.iprange (from the third json file)
  ]
} I tought about merging the the locals and then working with if statements because there is always a unique matching key element is the linked jsons. Hope this makes some sense

Comment: Please do not paste code in comments, edit your original question... and no, what you are saying is not making much sense ... you thought about merging locals and working with if statements ... don't think do it if you get an error post another question